# How to extract a part of string?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, ash

I have string contains a path

```
string="toto.titi.1.tata.2.abc.def"
```

I want to extract the substring which is situated after `toto.titi.1.tata.2.`. but 1 and 2 here are examples and could be other numbers.

In general: I want to extract the substring which situated after `toto.titi.[i].tata.[j].`.

`[i]` and `[j]` are a numbers

How to do it?

Comment: Do you know regex tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cut

```
 echo $string | cut -f6- -d'.'
```

Answer (score 6):

Pure `bash` solution:

```
[[ $string =~ toto\.titi\.[0-9]+\.tata\.[0-9]+\.(.*$) ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "$result"
```

Comment: nice! I've searched for that before suggesting a `sed` solution

Comment: Can also say `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: No you can't. `bash` doesn't support `\d`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternate `bash` solution that uses parameter expansion instead of a regular expression:

```
echo "${string#toto.titi.[0-9].tata.[0-9].}"
```

If the numbers can be multi-digit values (i.e., greater than 9), you would need to use an extended pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo "${string#toto.titi.+([0-9]).tata.+([0-9]).}"
```

Comment: a good answer (+1). but you can avoid the use of `shopt -s extglob` by using `echo "${string#toto.titi.[0-9]*.tata.[0-9]*.}"`

Comment: This is a pattern, not a regular expression. `[0-9]*` would match a single digit followed by *anything*, not a (possibly empty) series of digits.

Comment: For my case I m sure that my string contains only numbers. so for my case it's ok to use `[0-9]*`

Comment: In that case, you wouldn't even need to specify the numbers; `${string#toto.titi.*.tata.*.}` would probably work (since the `#` operator will match the shortest string possible).

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
echo ${string} | sed -re 's/^toto\.titi\.[[:digit:]]+\.tata\.[[:digit:]]+\.//'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:

`echo "$string" | cut -d '.'  -f 6-`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`. Like this:

```
string="toto.titi.1.tata.2.abc.def"
string=$(sed 's/toto\.titi\.[0-9]\.tata\.[0-9]\.//' <<< "$string")
echo "$string"
```

Output:

```
abc.def
```

Comment: @dogbane I expect that under the hood it is almost the same. But however, I have updated the post

Answer (score 0):

try this awk line:

```
awk -F'toto\\.titi\\.[0-9]+\\.tata\\.[0-9]+\\.' '{print $2}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "toto.titi.1.tata.2.abc.def"|awk -F'toto\\.titi\\.[0-9]+\\.tata\\.[0-9]+\\.' '{print $2}'
abc.def
```